# Split a column into 2 columns with "." separator R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following dataset:

```
the_data <- data.frame(the_col = "a.1","b.2","c.3","d.4")
```

I try to split it into 2 columns. It seems that is a replicated question but what makes it different is the separator I want (the dot). I tried:

```
the_data %>% separate(the_col, into = c("alfa","beta"), sep = ".")
```

But I receive a warning and not what I want:

```
 alfa beta X.b.2. X.c.3. X.d.4.
1              b.2    c.3    d.4
```

what I want is:

```
alfa   beta
a      1
b      2 
c      3
d      4
```

Could you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can get the data in long format and then use `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(the_data, cols = everything()) %>%
  separate(value, into = c('alpha', 'beta'), sep = "\\.") %>%
  select(-name)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  alpha beta 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     1    
#2 b     2    
#3 c     3    
#4 d     4
```

---

Using base R, we can split the unlisted string on `"."`, convert it into two column dataframe and add names to it.

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(unlist(the_data), '\\.')), 
         c('alpha', 'beta'))
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, thank you very much, it's been nice from you the two answers!

Answer (score 3):

```
the_data <- data.frame(the_col = c("a.1","b.2","c.3","d.4")) %>% 
  separate("the_col", c("alpha", "beta"), sep = "\\.")
# R> the_data 
#   alpha beta
# 1     a    1
# 2     b    2
# 3     c    3
# 4     d    4
```

I think your problem was that

1. `separate` takes a regex as its 2nd argument, and `.` matches any character in regex, unless you escape it with `\\`
2. The values which you intended to go into column `the_col` should have been in a vector.

Comment: Hello @David T, thank you for the answer, indeed the separator I was using was `"."`so I think that's the root of the problem, as you mention `.`is any character in regex and I didn't know how to represent it.