# Create two numeric columns from One character column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

The confidence interval column is of type character

| confidence_interval |
| --- |
| (245.0 - 345.2) |
| (434.1 - 432.1) |
| (123.5 - 1,120.2) |

I want to create two numeric columns like Upper Interval which has first value in the parentheses and lower interval which contains the second value

| Upper Interval | Lower Interval |
| --- | --- |
| 245.0 | 345.2 |
| 434.1 | 432.1 |
| 123.5 | 1120.2 |

How can this be done using R?

Thanks

Comment: Would something like  ```strsplit(confidence_interval, ",")``` help?

Comment: hi, this didn't split the column it just copies the same to another column

Comment: Hello @nish, can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi @PaulStaffordAllen, I have tried using strsplit as David suggested but with unlist(), unlist(strsplit(table$ConfidenceInterval, ","))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787280/split-a-column-into-2-columns-with-separator-r here's a similar question which should show a bit more of the syntax of how to get the two columns from 1.  I'd suggest then looking into how to drop the "(" characters and then convert to numeric.  Searching stack overflow (or just google) should give you a large number of examples to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
ci <- c('(245.0,345.2)', '(434.1,432.1)', '(123.5,901.2)')

values <- strsplit(gsub('\\(|\\)', '', ci), split = ",")

upper <- sapply(values, function(x) as.numeric(x[[1]]))
lower <- sapply(values, function(x) as.numeric(x[[2]]))

upper
#> [1] 245.0 434.1 123.5
lower
#> [1] 345.2 432.1 901.2
```

I use `gsub` to remove the parentheses, and then `strsplit` to split the values of each side of the `,`. Then i use `sapply` to return this a vector as the return value of `strsplit` is a list of lists.

**OP question was edited**

If separator between value is is ' - ' then you should use `values <- strsplit(gsub('\\(|\\)', '', ci), split = " - ")`

The `split` parameter in `strsplit` is what the function will use to split the strings into two parts.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. If the value has comma in it as well like 1,239.9, NA is being returned. How to remove that comma from that value?

Comment: If the numbers can have commas then they are ambiguous, eg `(100,100,100)`.  Unless there is always a single decimal point?

Comment: Hmm.. i do not have a good solution for that. If the data is from some other editor/program, maybe you can try to reformat the values there, so that they do not use  ',' as a decimal separator.

Comment: comma is not used as decimal separator. I have edited the data in the question for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Ah, then just change `strsplit(gsub('\\(|\\)', '', ci), split = ",")` to `strsplit(gsub('\\(|\\)', '', ci), split = " - ")`. I will edit answer.

Answer (score 4):

`extract()` from `tidyr` fits your case.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  extract(confidence_interval, into = c("Upper", "Lower"),
          regex = "\\((.+),(.+)\\)", convert = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Upper Lower
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  245   345.
# 2  434.  432.
# 3  124.  901.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `sapply` with `strsplit` and `gsub`

```
setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(df$confidence_interval, " - "), function(x)
  gsub("\\(|\\)", "", x)))), c("Upper Interval", "Lower Interval"))
  Upper Interval Lower Interval
1          245.0          345.2
2          434.1          432.1
3          123.5        1,901.2
```

##### Data

```
df)
structure(list(confidence_interval = c("(245.0 - 345.2)", "(434.1 - 432.1)",
"(123.5 - 1,901.2)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(confidence_interval, ~ str_remove_all(.x, "[^0-9,\\.]"))) %>%
  separate(col = confidence_interval,
           into = c("higher", "lower"),
           sep = ",", convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  higher lower
   <dbl> <dbl>
1   245   345.
2   434.  432.
3   124.  901.
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

ci <- c('(245.0,345.2)', '(434.1,432.1)', '(123.5,901.2)')      
data.frame(ci) |> 
  mutate(ci2 = stringr::str_replace_all(ci, "\\(|\\)", "")) |> 
  separate(ci2, c('upper', 'lower'), sep =",", convert = TRUE)
#>              ci upper lower
#> 1 (245.0,345.2) 245.0 345.2
#> 2 (434.1,432.1) 434.1 432.1
#> 3 (123.5,901.2) 123.5 901.2
```

Comment: You should add `convert = TRUE` into `separate()` to convert `upper` and `lower` to numeric.

Comment: @`Darren Tsai` thank you. I will.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strcapture`:

```
ci <- c('(245.0,345.2)', '(434.1,432.1)', '(123.5,901.2)')

pattern <- "\\(([-.0-9]+),([-.0-9]+)\\)"
strcapture(pattern, ci, data.frame(upper.interval=numeric(), lower.interval=numeric()))

  upper.interval lower.interval
1          245.0          345.2
2          434.1          432.1
3          123.5          901.2
```

Comment: Nice use of `strcapture`! Here is a suggestion. Column names with spaces are invalid in R's `data.frame`, and the spaces will be replaced with dot symbols by default. If you persist in using it, you should add `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame()`.

Comment: Thanks, have edited.  Best to avoid needless spaces altogether I guess.